# Google Signin Android App, How to check to make sure the User has not revoked the authorization?

Tags: android, google-signin

This question is about the new `GoogleSignInApi` explained [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/).

Suppose I go through the steps and I acquire the email, first name, last name and for good measure an Id.

Suppose I save all this information on the device (either via `Preferences` or via `SQLite`) so that in future I don't need to ask the user for his authorisation again.

The question is how to make sure that the Id and the info is still valid, 
Perhaps by next time, the user has revoked his authorisation, or that he has changed some of the profile info.

Now before you answer that I have to use `SilenSignIn`, let me say, that silent sign in won't work. Because for the Initial signin I use another `Activity` called through `startIntentForResult` after I get the profile I close that activity, I don't want to have to call that activity again, because the point of saving the information is not to call the activity again.

Comment: I believe it handles this automatically? Assuming the user doesn't kill the app.

Comment: well, that's actually my question. suppose the user signs in whereby his information is obtained as explained in the link above and then kills the app. A while later he launches the app, where his info has been saved, the question is what if in the meantime he has revoked the authorization he had granted the app, and the stored information is not valid. My question is  how to validate the info without having the user signin everytime and invoking the activity that was invoked the first time.

Comment: Can't you just try using the token? If it fails you know it has invalidated and prompt them to login again. You can't store their credentials, but you can probably store the token.

Comment: good. you are probably talking about Id token. So the question becomes how to use the Id token? there was something said about sending the token to a back-end server on google signin api manual. Is that how I have to go about it?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried to persist logins like this before. You can try reading the documentation to see how it's used then mimic that maybe. The docs on this are pretty good.